# Nginx protect HTTP flood without rate limit (weed out fake traffic)

Tags: nginx

I am having some trouble protecting against HTTP floods in nginx... I have already tried rate limiting, but in an attack as large as the one I am recieving (1,000,000 r/s +) it is not useful. A friend of mine claims that he has a simple method to detect ANY "fake traffic" from an HTTP flood, I am trying to figure it out. His site does not go down from the 1,000,000 r/s attack we are speaking of... This is a test page he has setup to test the protection, http://testprot.venomservers.net/. I am really having hard time figuring it out.

Comment: And how would the server have any idea if a browser had JavaScript? What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: As someone who uses NoScript, I think this would be a bad solution to whatever your real problem is, if it were possible.

Comment: Are you trying to stop spambots?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have updated the question.

Comment: @Ladadadada Please see the updated question.

Comment: @platforms Please see the update question

Comment: You could just implement some sort of rate-limiting solution, either in `nginx` or using your system firewall (e.g., `iptables` under Linux).  It looks as if `nginx` has a rate limiting module and there are lots of examples out there on how to use it.

Comment: @larsks I have done that already, but in an attack as large as the one I am recieving (1,000,000 r/s +) it is not useful. A friend of mine claims that he has a simple method to detect ANY "fake traffic" from an HTTP flood, I am trying to figure it out. His site does not go down from the 1,000,000 r/s attack we are speaking of... This is a test page he has setup to test the protection, http://testprot.venomservers.net/. I am really having hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Get a hardware firewall. Problem solved.

If you want to block fake traffic, setup a BSD box, throw on snort and other HIDS/IDS to block "fake traffic".

nginx was not designed for that.